# Как вернуть результат в UTF-8 в PHP

Tags: php, decode

Ко мне в контроллер php приходит строка в таком формате

**"["21) \u0424\u043e\u0441\u0444\u043e\u0440","Gt"]"**

Если я делаю json_decode("["21) \u0424\u043e\u0441\u0444\u043e\u0440","Gt"]") у меня это превращается в массив и корректный перевод

```
array(0:["21) Фосфор"],1:["Gt"])
```

Я пытался сделать json_encode(json_decode("["21) \u0424\u043e\u0441\u0444\u043e\u0440","Gt"]")) но результата как такового нет.

А мне просто нужна строка для записи в Базу с нормальной кодировкой.
"["21) Фосфор","Gt"]"
Прошу любой помощи.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
json_decode($json, false, 512, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
```

`JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` означает "не кодировать многобайтовые символы Unicode (по умолчанию они кодируются как \uXXXX"

Comment: у меня без этого был массив с корректными значениями, но мне бы преобразовать "["21) \u0424\u043e\u0441\u0444\u043e\u0440","Gt"]" в "["21) Фосфор","Gt"]"
Но я кажись понял, до момента передачи я захожу в массив и вытаскиваю в другую переменную строки 

$targetRus = '';
            foreach (json_decode("["21) \u0424\u043e\u0441\u0444\u043e\u0440","Gt"]") as $key){
                $targetRus.= $key.',';
            }

Comment: Я не понял что ты хотел сказать этим комментом. Ответ что надо делать я написал